# Do I need extention to enable for XML /XSLT as I am getting this error too i.e MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xslt

I have this set of code and what I am getting is this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I am unable to figure it out what exactly the issue is...Do I need to enable some extention in my server..or whay

here is the link of the exact script:

http://cfactura.info/jorgemiron/nomina/n5.php

```
   <?php
include('../Connections/conexion.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT N.*,N.RFC 'rfc1', E.*
    FROM nomina N
        JOIN empresa E ON (E.id = N.idEmpresa)
    WHERE N.id =".$_GET['id'];
//$sql = "select * from nomina where id='".$_GET["id"]."'";
//echo $sql;
//echo $sql; die();
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
//exit;
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
//$row['rfc1'] = substr($row['rfc1'],0,strlen($row['rfc1'])-1);
//echo $row['rfc1'];
//die();

$sqlFolios = "SELECT * FROM folios_asignados WHERE (id_empresa = ".$row['idEmpresa'].")";
//echo $sqlFolios;
$resFolios = mysql_query($sqlFolios) or die(mysql_error());
$rowFolios = mysql_fetch_assoc($resFolios);

##########################################################
# PASO1. Crea un CFDi de nomina
#
# Regresa un texto en la variable $cfdi
##########################################################
# Partimos de un CFDi a medias, conservando declaracion de esquemas
$fecha = substr($row['fecha_emision'], 0, -6);
//echo "<pre>";print_r($fecha);die;


$cfdi = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:nomina="http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina" xmlns:ecb="http://www.sat.gob.mx/ecb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:implocal="http://www.sat.gob.mx/implocal" xmlns:bfa2="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2" xmlns:terceros="http://www.sat.gob.mx/terceros" xmlns:detallista="http://www.sat.gob.mx/detallista" xmlns:psgecfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/psgecfd" xmlns:ecc="http://www.sat.gob.mx/ecc" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" version = "3.2" folio = "" fecha = "$fecha" sello = "" formaDePago = "" noCertificado="00001000000302229462" certificado = "" subTotal="0.00" descuento="0.00" motivoDescuento="Deducciones nomina" total="0.00" tipoDeComprobante="egreso" metodoDePago="" LugarExpedicion="" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/detallista http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/detallista/detallista.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/implocal http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/implocal/implocal.xsd http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2 http://www.buzonfiscal.com/schema/xsd/Addenda_BF_v2.2.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina
http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/nomina/nomina12.xsd">
  <cfdi:Emisor nombre="OFELIA DAVILA IBARRA" rfc="DAIO630114T46">
    <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal codigoPostal="" pais="Mexico" estado="" municipio="" calle="" colonia="" localidad="" />
    <cfdi:RegimenFiscal/>
  </cfdi:Emisor>
  <cfdi:Receptor rfc="">
  </cfdi:Receptor>
  <cfdi:Conceptos>
  </cfdi:Conceptos>
  <cfdi:Impuestos>
    <cfdi:Traslados>
      <cfdi:Traslado importe="" tasa="16.00" impuesto="IVA"/>
    </cfdi:Traslados>
  </cfdi:Impuestos>
  <cfdi:Complemento>
   </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
XML;



//$cfdi = preg_replace("/\[RFC\]/",$row["rfc1"],$cfdi);

# Convierte a objeto DOM $xml
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($cfdi);

$xmlcomprobante = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3', 'Comprobante')->item(0);
if (strlen(trim($row['serie'])) > 0) {
    $xmlcomprobante->setAttribute('serie', trim($row['serie']));
}
//$xmlcomprobante->setAttribute('folio', $row['numero']);
$xmlcomprobante->setAttribute('folio',$id);
$xmlcomprobante->setAttribute('formaDePago', trim($row['forma_pago_sat']));
$xmlcomprobante->setAttribute('metodoDePago', trim($row['metodo_pago']));
$xmlcomprobante->setAttribute('LugarExpedicion', trim($row['expedicion']));
if ($row['numctapago'] != NULL)
{   
    $xmlcomprobante->setAttribute('NumCtaPago', $row['numctapago']);
}    


$xmlemisor = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3', 'Emisor')->item(0);
$xmlemisordomicilio = $xmlemisor->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3', 'DomicilioFiscal')->item(0);
$xmlemisordomicilio->setAttribute('codigoPostal', trim($row['zip']));
$xmlemisordomicilio->setAttribute('pais', utf8_encode(trim($row['pais'])));
$xmlemisordomicilio->setAttribute('estado', utf8_encode(trim($row['estado'])));
$xmlemisordomicilio->setAttribute('municipio', utf8_encode(trim($row['municipio'])));
$xmlemisordomicilio->setAttribute('calle', utf8_encode(trim($row['domicilio'])));
$xmlemisordomicilio->setAttribute('colonia', utf8_encode(trim($row['colonia'])));
$xmlemisordomicilio->setAttribute('localidad', utf8_encode(trim($row['ciudad'])));
unset($xmlemisordomicilio);
//echo utf8_encode(trim($row['ciudad']));die;
$xmlemisorregimen = $xmlemisor->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3', 'RegimenFiscal')->item(0);
$xmlemisorregimen->setAttribute('Regimen', trim($row['regimen']));
unset($xmlemisorregimen);
unset($xmlemisor);


# Modifica codigos semifijos
$xmlreceptor = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3', 'Receptor')->item(0);

$receptornombre = utf8_encode(trim($row['nombre']) . " " . trim($row['apellido_paterno']) . " " . trim($row['apellido_materno']));
if (strlen($receptornombre) > 0) {
    $xmlreceptor->setAttribute('nombre', $receptornombre);
//echo $receptornombre;die;
}
//print_r($receptornombre);die;
$maxreceptorrfclen = 13;
$receptorrfc = utf8_encode(trim($row['rfc1']));
if (strlen($receptorrfc) > $maxreceptorrfclen) {
    $receptorrfc = substr($receptorrfc, 0, $maxreceptorrfclen);
}
$xmlreceptor->setAttribute('rfc', $receptorrfc);
unset($xmlreceptor);

# Agrega concepto
$xmlconceptos = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3', 'Conceptos')->item(0);
$xmlconcepto = $xml->createElementNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3', 'Concepto');
$xmlconcepto->setAttribute('cantidad', 1);
$xmlconcepto->setAttribute('unidad', 'Servicio');
$xmlconcepto->setAttribute('descripcion', 'Sueldo');
$xmlconcepto->setAttribute('valorUnitario', number_format($row['total'], 2, '.', ''));
$xmlconcepto->setAttribute('importe', number_format($row['total'], 2, '.', ''));
$xmlconceptos->appendChild($xmlconcepto);
unset($xmlconcepto);


$c = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3', 'Comprobante')->item(0);
$c->getElementsByTagName('Impuestos')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('Traslados')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('Traslado')->item(0)->setAttribute('importe', $row['iva']);



# Agrega nodo nomina
$xmlcomplemento = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3', 'Complemento')->item(0);
$xmlNomina = $xml->createElementNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina12', 'Nomina');
$xmlNomina->setAttribute('Version', 1.2);


    //$xmlNomina->setAttribute('RegistroPatronal', $row['registroPatronal']);
//$xmlNomina->setAttribute('NumEmpleado', $row['numEmpleado']);
//$xmlNomina->setAttribute('Curp', $row['CURP']);
//$xmlNomina->setAttribute('TipoRegimen', $row['tipoRegimen']);
if ($row['imss'] != NULL)
{
    $xmlNomina->setAttribute('NumSeguridadSocial', $row['imss']);
}
$xmlNomina->setAttribute('FechaPago', $row['FechaPago']);
$xmlNomina->setAttribute('FechaInicialPago', $row['FechaInicialPago']);
$xmlNomina->setAttribute('FechaFinalPago', $row['FechaFinalPago']);
//$xmlNomina->setAttribute('NumDiasPagados', $row['numDiasPagados']);



$xmlNomina->setAttribute('NumDiasPagados', 30);
if ($row['Departamento'] != NULL)
{
    $xmlNomina->setAttribute('Departamento', $row['Departamento']);
}
if ($row['clabe'] != 0)
    $xmlNomina->setAttribute('CLABE', $row['clabe']);
//if ($row['banco'] != 0)
  //  $xmlNomina->setAttribute('Banco', $row['banco']);
//if ($row['FechaIniRelLaboral'] != '0001-01-01')
  //  $xmlNomina->setAttribute('FechaInicioRelLaboral', $row['FechaIniRelLaboral']);
if ($row['antiguedad'] != 0)
{
    //$xmlNomina->setAttribute('Antiguedad', $row['antiguedad']);
}
if ($row['puesto'] != NULL)
{
    //$xmlNomina->setAttribute('Puesto', $row['puesto']);
}




if ($row['tipoContrato'] != NULL)
{
    //$xmlNomina->setAttribute('TipoContrato', $row['tipoContrato']);
}
if ($row['tipoJornada'] != NULL)
{
    //$xmlNomina->setAttribute('TipoJornada', $row['tipoJornada']);
}
//$xmlNomina->setAttribute('PeriodicidadPago', $row['periodicidadPago']);
if ($row['salariobase'] != 0)
{
    //$xmlNomina->setAttribute('SalarioBaseCotApor', $row['salariobase']);
}
if ($row['riesgoPuesto'] != 0)
{
    //$xmlNomina->setAttribute('RiesgoPuesto', $row['riesgoPuesto']);
}
if ($row['departmento'] != 0)
{
    $xmlNomina->setAttribute('Departamento', $row['departmento']);
}

//$xmlNomina->setAttribute('CLABE', $row['clabe']);



//echo "....".$row['SalarioDiarioIntegrado'].".....";
//$xmlNomina->setAttribute('SalarioDiarioIntegrado', number_format($row['salarioDiarioIntegrado'],2,'.',''));




//Busco las percepciones
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM percepciones WHERE (idNomina = " . $_GET['id'] . ")";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2);

$totPercepcion = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0)
{
    $totalg = $totale = 0;
    $xmlPercepciones = $xml->createElementNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina', 'Percepciones');
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) 
    {
        $xmlPercepcion = $xml->createElementNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina', 'Percepcion');
        $totalg = $totalg + $row2['ImporteGravado'];
        $totale = $totale + $row2['ImporteExento'];
        $xmlPercepcion->setAttribute('TipoPercepcion', str_pad($row2['TipoPercepcion'],3,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT));
        $xmlPercepcion->setAttribute('Clave', str_pad($row2['Clave'],3,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT));
        $xmlPercepcion->setAttribute('Concepto', $row2['Concepto']);
        $xmlPercepcion->setAttribute('ImporteGravado', $row2['ImporteGravado']);
        $xmlPercepcion->setAttribute('ImporteExento', $row2['ImporteExento']);
        $xmlPercepciones->appendChild($xmlPercepcion);

    }
    $xmlPercepciones->setAttribute('TotalGravado', $totalg);
    $xmlPercepciones->setAttribute('TotalExento', $totale);
    $xmlNomina->appendChild($xmlPercepciones);
}
$totPercepcion = $totalg + $totale;

/*

//Busco las deducciones
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM deducciones WHERE (idNomina = " . $_GET['id'] . ")";
$res3 = mysql_query($sql3);

$totDeducciones = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($res3) > 0)
{
    $totalg = $totale = 0;
    $xmlDeducciones = $xml->createElementNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina', 'Deducciones');
    while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)) 
    {
        $xmlDeduccion = $xml->createElementNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina', 'Deduccion');
        $totalg = $totalg + $row3['ImporteGravado'];
        $totale = $totale + $row3['ImporteExento'];
        $xmlDeduccion->setAttribute('TipoDeduccion', str_pad($row3['TipoDeduccion'],"3","0",STR_PAD_LEFT));
        $xmlDeduccion->setAttribute('Clave', str_pad($row3['Clave'],"3","0",STR_PAD_LEFT));
        $xmlDeduccion->setAttribute('Concepto', $row3['Concepto']);
        $xmlDeduccion->setAttribute('ImporteGravado', $row3['ImporteGravado']);
        $xmlDeduccion->setAttribute('ImporteExento', $row3['ImporteExento']);
        $xmlDeducciones->appendChild($xmlDeduccion);

    }
    $xmlDeducciones->setAttribute('TotalGravado', $totalg);
    $xmlDeducciones->setAttribute('TotalExento', $totale);
    $xmlNomina->appendChild($xmlDeducciones);
}
$totDeducciones = $totalg + $totale;



//Busco las incapacidades
$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM incapacidades WHERE (idNomina = " . $_GET['id'] . ")";
$res4 = mysql_query($sql4);

$totIncapacidades = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($res4) > 0)
{
    $xmlIncapacidades = $xml->createElementNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina', 'Incapacidades');
    while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res4)) 
    {
        $xmlIncapacidad = $xml->createElementNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina', 'Incapacidad');
        $xmlIncapacidad->setAttribute('DiasIncapacidad', $row4['DiasIncapacidad']);
        $xmlIncapacidad->setAttribute('TipoIncapacidad', $row4['TipoIncapacidad']);
        $xmlIncapacidad->setAttribute('Descuento', $row4['Descuento']);
        $xmlIncapacidades->appendChild($xmlIncapacidad);
        $totIncapacidades = $totIncapacidades + $row4['Descuento'];
    }
    $xmlNomina->appendChild($xmlIncapacidades);
}



//Busco las HorasExtra
$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM horasExtras WHERE (idNomina = " . $_GET['id'] . ")";
$res5 = mysql_query($sql5);

$totHorasExtra = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($res5) > 0)
{
    $xmlHorasExtras = $xml->createElementNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina', 'HorasExtras');
    while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res5)) 
    {
        $xmlHorasExtra = $xml->createElementNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina', 'HorasExtra');
        $xmlHorasExtra->setAttribute('Dias', $row5['dias']);
        $xmlHorasExtra->setAttribute('TipoHoras', $row5['tipoHoras']);
        $xmlHorasExtra->setAttribute('HorasExtra', $row5['horasExtra']);
        $xmlHorasExtra->setAttribute('ImportePagado', $row5['ImportePagado']);
        $xmlHorasExtras->appendChild($xmlHorasExtra);
        $totHorasExtra = $totHorasExtra + $row5['ImportePagado'];
    }
    $xmlNomina->appendChild($xmlHorasExtras);
}


//Totalizo los importes
$descuentos = number_format(($totDeducciones  + $totIncapacidades), 2, '.', '');
$xmlcomprobante->setAttribute('descuento', $descuentos);
$xmlcomprobante->setAttribute('subTotal', number_format($totPercepcion + $totHorasExtra, 2, '.', ''));
$xmlcomprobante->setAttribute('total', number_format($totPercepcion + $totHorasExtra - $totDeducciones  - $totIncapacidades , 2, '.', ''));

 */

 $xmlcomplemento->appendChild($xmlNomina);

unset($xmlcomprobante);
unset($xmlNomina);
unset($xmlcomplemento);



# Reconvierte a texto
$cfdi = $xml->saveXML();

###############################################################
# PASO2. Firma el comprobante que esta en $cfdi en modo texto
#
# Regresa el comprobante firmado en la misma variable $cfdi
###############################################################
# Extrae cadena original
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$XSL = new DOMDocument();
$XSL->load('http://www.sat.mx/cfd/3/cadenaoriginal_3_2/cadenaoriginal_3_2.xslt', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
error_reporting(0); # Se deshabilitan los errores pues el xssl de la cadena esta en version 2 y eso genera algunos warnings
$xslt->importStylesheet($XSL);
error_reporting(E_ALL); # Se habilitan de nuevo los errores (se asume que originalmente estaban habilitados)

$c = $xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3', 'Comprobante')->item(0);
$cadena = $xslt->transformToXML($c);
unset($xslt, $XSL);

$sql4 = "UPDATE nomina SET cadena_original = '" . $cadena . "' WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'];
$res4 = mysql_query($sql4) or die(mysql_error());

//genero el sello digital
$key = <<<TEXT
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
TEXT;

// $pass = trim($rowFolios['clave']);
$llave = openssl_pkey_get_private($key);
openssl_sign($cadena, $sello, $llave);
$sello = base64_encode($sello);

$certificado="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";

# Incorpora los tres elementos al cfdi
$c->setAttribute('certificado', $certificado);
$c->setAttribute('sello', $sello);


# regresa el resultado
$cfdi = $xml->saveXML();

unset($c, $certificado, $sello, $cadena, $key);

###############################################################
# PASO4. Timbra el CFDI en la variable $cfdi con TimbreFiscal
#
#        4.1) Ensobreta
#        4.2) Env?a a TimbreFiscal
#        4.3) Recibe un timbre (o procesa un error)
# Regresa el $cfdi intacto y $timbre
###############################################################
# Convierte a modelo DOM
#$xml = new DOMDocument();
#$xml->loadXML($cfdi) or die("\n\n\nXML no valido");
# Valida CFDi contra esquema
#$xml->schemaValidate('cfdv3.xsd') or die("\n\n\nCFDi no valido");
# Sobre con el request
$envtext = <<<XML
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cfdi="http://cfdi.service.ediwinws.edicom.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cfdi:getCfdi>
         <cfdi:user></cfdi:user>
         <cfdi:password></cfdi:password>
         <cfdi:file></cfdi:file>
      </cfdi:getCfdi>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
XML;
$env = new DOMDocument();
$env->loadXML($envtext) or die("\n\n\nError interno en el sobre");

$req = $env->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://cfdi.service.ediwinws.edicom.com', 'getCfdi')->item(0);
$req->getElementsByTagName('user')->item(0)->nodeValue = "CFO1010219Z8";
$req->getElementsByTagName('password')->item(0)->nodeValue = "gjstbaarg";
$req->getElementsByTagName('file')->item(0)->nodeValue  = base64_encode($cfdi);
//echo "<pre>";print_r($env->saveXML());die;
# Paso 4.2 Env?a a TimbreFiscal y 4.3 recibe un timbre o procesa un error
$process = curl_init('https://cfdiws.sedeb2b.com/EdiwinWS/services/CFDi');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml', 'charset=utf-8', 'SOAPAction: ""'));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $env->saveXML());
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$timbre = curl_exec($process);

curl_close($process);
if (!$timbre) {
    echo curl_error($process);
    die("Error en comunicacion\n");
}

###############################################################
# PASO5. Integra el timbre recibido en $timbre en el $cfdi
#
# Regresa el $cfdi ya integrado con el timbre
###############################################################

# Valida que realmente haya regresado un timbre
$sobretimbre = new DOMDocument();
$sobretimbre->loadXML($timbre) or die("\n\n\nXML de respuesta no valido\n");
# Extrae el timbre (si existe)
$xmltimbre = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
# Extrae el nodo

if (!$sobretimbre->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://cfdi.service.ediwinws.edicom.com', 'getCfdiReturn')->item(0)) {
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($sobretimbre);die;

    $err = $sobretimbre->getElementsByTagName ('faultstring') or die("\n\n\nError de validacion\n$return");
    $errStr = "";
    foreach ($err as $node) {
      $errStr = $node->nodeValue."<br/>";
    }
    //die("\n\n\n$errStr\n");
        echo "ERROR EN EL PROCESO DE TIMBRADO: ".$errStr;
    $goto = "index.php";
    echo "<p><input name='submit' type='button' value='Finalizar' onClick='javascript: window.location.href=\"$goto\"'></p>";        
    die();
}

$base64data = $sobretimbre->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://cfdi.service.ediwinws.edicom.com', 'getCfdiReturn')->item(0)->textContent;

$zipdata = base64_decode($base64data);

$zipfilename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'cfdi');
$zipfile = fopen($zipfilename,'w');
fwrite($zipfile, $zipdata);
fclose($zipfile);

$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open($zipfilename) === TRUE) {
    $timbrecfdi = $zip->getFromName("SIGN_XML_COMPROBANTE_3_0.xml");
    $xmltimbre->loadXML($timbrecfdi) or die("\n\n\nXML no valido");
    $zip->close();
} else {

    die("\n\n\nError de zip\n$return");
}

$t = $xmltimbre->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital', 'TimbreFiscalDigital')->item(0);
$sellosat = $t->getAttribute('selloSAT');
$uuid = $t->getAttribute('UUID');
//echo "!!!".$uuid."!!!";
$fechatimbrado = $t->getAttribute('FechaTimbrado');
$certificadoSAT = $t->getAttribute('noCertificadoSAT');
$version = $t->getAttribute('version');
$sellocfd = $t->getAttribute('selloCFD');

$complemento = "||".$version."|".$uuid."|".$fechatimbrado."|".$sellocfd."|".$certificadoSAT."||";

$cfdi = $xmltimbre->saveXML();

unset($timbre, $xml, $sobretimbre, $xmltimbre, $t);

$sql5 = "UPDATE nomina SET selloSAT = '".$sellosat."', UUID = '".$uuid. "', fechatimbrado = '" . $fechatimbrado . "', certificadoSAT = '" . $certificadoSAT . "', version = '" . $version . "', selloCFD = '" . $sellocfd . "', cadena_complemento = '" . $complemento."' WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
$res5 = mysql_query($sql5) or die(mysql_error());

$dir = 'archivos1/';
//$titulo = 'nomina' . $row['numero'] . '.xml';
$titulo = 'nomina' . $id . '.xml';
file_put_contents($dir.$titulo, $cfdi);
echo $link = "Click aqui para descargar el archivo: <a href='" . $dir.$titulo . "'>" . $titulo . "</a>";
echo "<br/><p>";
$goto = "vista_previa.php?id=" . $id;
echo "<input name='submit' type='button' value='Continuar' onClick='javascript: window.location.href=\"$goto\"'></p>";
?>
```

Comment: You have an error in one of the SQL statements. Fix the SQL, use prepared statements and/or escape properly. This is NOT an XML or PHP configuration problem.

Comment: @ThW ... Now this is what I am getting here...cfactura.info/jorgemiron/nomina/n5.php?id=102

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace
`$sqlFolios = "SELECT * FROM folios_asignados WHERE (id_empresa = ".$row['idEmpresa'].")";`
With
`$sqlFolios = "SELECT * FROM folios_asignados WHERE (id_empresa = '".$row['idEmpresa']."')";`

You need to surround `$row['idEmpresa']` with single quote marks.

Comment: I tried that but same result . Same error reflected. Not getting close to work it out!

Comment: It took the old syntax only and when I get this id then it is throwing this new error ...http://jorgemiron.cfactura.info/nomina/n5.php?id=102

Comment: Now this is what I am getting here...http://cfactura.info/jorgemiron/nomina/n5.php?id=102

Comment: You initially had a MySQL error. But not I think its something to do with your XML

Comment: Yes it is something related to XML ...See if you can help as there is a webservice to generate pdf report for employees...